# Development AppEngine Datastore, multiple rows with the same key

Tags: java, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

There are multiple rows in my development AppEngine Datastore admin interface with the same key: agpiYW5rLXJlY29uchULEghPbml4TWFpbBiAgICAgIDiCAw. The rows are on Page 2 and Page 3. I used CTRL-F to find them. How is this possible?

`http://localhost:8888/_ah/admin/datastore?kind=OnixMail`

```
Key                                             WriteOps ID/Name          date                         from
agpiYW5rLXJlY29uchULEghPbml4TWFpbBiAgICAgIDICAw 16       4820258976169984 Wed Oct 23 22:00:54 EDT 2013 me@me.com
agpiYW5rLXJlY29uchULEghPbml4TWFpbBiAgICAgIDiCAw 16       4934608185458688 Thu Oct 24 14:42:16 EDT 2013 email@email.com
```

I use the key to load and query for items, and if that is not really the key then I have a lot of work to do.

#### Version

SDK v1.8.5

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This are base64 encoded keys and the two that you list are not the same - difference is in the capital `I` and lower-case `i` (fourth char from the end). Ctrl-f search in browsers does case-insensitive search, so this two showed as the same.

Comment: Ahh! Are you sure they are Base64 encoded? http://www.base64decode.org/ gives a different result than `KeyFactory.stringToKey(k1).toString()`. Plus they don't end with `==`.

Comment: Good spot on the 'i' vs 'I'. I looked at that twice and didn't see it.

Comment: @Chloe - the `=` at the end is just a padding, to round to four chars: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64#Padding